# Selenium Webdriver Java: Testing Zopim chat functionality

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to test the functionality of a chat window similar to the zopim chat window using Selenium WebDriver Java. After troubleshooting for a longtime, I got to know that it is a different frame altogether in the webpage. So first I tried to open the window with the command pasted below and it worked, but now I am unable to perform any kind of action on the chat window. I am trying to enter the fields and click the button. I am a beginner in Selenium so after 2 days of trying on this issue but in vain. Kindly help! Thanks

Website: https://www.zopim.com/
The minimzed button on the right hand side corner at the bottom in green color "Leave us a message"

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[src='about:blank']")));
//click the iFrame
 new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By
                .xpath("//div[@class='meshim_widget_widgets_Favicon favicon']"))).click();
```

Comment: `By.cssSelector("iframe[src='about:blank']")` seriously? You did not think this odd?

Comment: <iframe frameborder="0" style="background-color: transparent; vertical-align: text-bottom; position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; overflow: hidden; display: block;" src="about:blank"> I have only these details to locate the iframe hence used in that way. Please suggest if you have a better idea. I have tried using <driver.switchto().frame(0)> also but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's just that *you are locating a different iframe*. You have to improve your locator:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[.//textarea[@name='message']]"))
```

Here we are locating the `iframe` having the `textarea` element with `name="message"` - our chat message text field.

Comment: I have tried the command you gave and also I tried with the message text field id but no luck... driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[.//textarea[@name='Message']]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[.//textarea[@name='Message']]")).sendKeys("Test");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[.//textarea[@id='___$_61']]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[.//textarea[@id='___$_61']]")).sendKeys("Test");

Comment: @Codelearner6 what do you mean by "no luck". What error are you getting and on which line? Thanks.

Comment: I am getting the following error - org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//iframe[.//textarea[@name='Message']]"}
on the line where i have the following line - driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[.//textarea[@name='Message']]")).click(); I also tried with its id - driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[.//textarea[@id='___$_61']]")).click(); but getting the same error

Comment: @Codelearner6 you need to wait for it to become present - it appears with a delay.

Comment: I tried giving some wait time but still throwing the NoSuchElementException, below is my code: 
 driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[src='about:blank']")));
  //click the iFrame
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
     ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By
 .xpath("//div[@class='meshim_widget_widgets_Favicon favicon']"))).click();
//driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//Thread.sleep(15000);
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
 ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//iframe[.//textarea[@id='___$_61']]"))).click();